# Listing only Polygon Feature Classes in IMxDocument Using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, geometry, mxd

I am using VS 2017 with ArcObjects trying to list all polygons in IMxDocument to be used as clip feature in my add-In. I have a WinForms application and the following code:

```
IMxDocument document = (IMxDocument)ArcMap.Document;
IMap map = document.FocusMap;

for (int index = 0; index < map.LayerCount; index++)
{
    ILayer layer = map.get_Layer(index);  
}
```

I know I will need to use

`geometry.GeometryType != esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon`

at some point in my code, but I could not manage my code to achieve that.

How can I get only polygons?

Comment: Are you trying to list all polygon feature classes in your .mxd or are you trying to loop through all polygons in a single feature class?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: which one? all poly feature class OR all polys in a single feature class?

Comment: All polygons in IMxDocument, like builtupArea, landUse, adminUnits, etc. They are all polygon features. I need to list them all

Comment: You are mixing terminology. A Featureclass can have many features. So saying I want to list features is very confusing. Think of a FeatureClass as a LAYER and a LAYER can have many polygons. So to Clarify what @Dowlers was correctly asking, are you asking to list the LAYERS (which are holding polygons) in your map OR list the polygons in a single LAYER?

Comment: Ohhh, forgive my week knowledge in that. You are right. Considering that good note, I would say Featureclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IFeatureLayer2.ShapeType may work for you.

Below is some untested code

```
for (int index = 0; index < map.LayerCount; index++)
{
    ILayer layer = map.get_Layer(index); 
    IfeatureLayer2 pFeatLay = (IfeatureLayer2) layer 
    If (pFeatLay.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon )
    {
         //Do stuff
    }

}
```